# It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):

Tags: java, recursion

It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):

Comment: Did you try commenting out this line and testing it yourself, and checking the result?

Comment: See [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Answer (score 1):

It is backtracking logic. See those instruction this way (comments added):

```
sb.append(board[i][j]); // Mark
if(i == rows-1 && j == cols-1){
    out.add(sb.toString());

   /*
   Here, you reached the bottom-right element of the matrix. 
   You can no longer go down or right, so you perform a backtracking 
   by deleting the last element read. 
   */
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    return;
}
search(i+1,j,board,sb,out); // Search Down
search(i,j+1,board,sb,out); // Search Right

/*
Here, you exhausted the elements on bottom and right 
(because you just returned from the two search() calls). Perform a backtracking by
removing the last element (which is a dead end) before returning to the calling 
recursion step:
*/
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); // Un-Mark
```